# Why does this exported cube have more vertices than I expected?

Tags: md5mesh

I'm trying to export `md5mesh` models. Just as a test I decided to export a simple cube (i.e. with 8 vertices). When I opened the `md5mesh` file it lists the following:

```
numverts 24
numtris 12
numweights 24
```

Obviously the number of triangles makes sense: 6 faces * 2 to triangulate = 12.

The model only has one bone so again it even makes sense that there is one weight for each vertex. The question is though, why is the file listing *24 vertices*?

Is the problem the exporter or is this normal for `md5mesh`'s? Is it something that you have to rectify when you come to parsing the file in engine? I don't want to be parsing or drawing duplicated vertices without reason.

I'm guessing it's something to do with shading and normals. Is it a case of listing each vert 3 times, one for each facing normal?

Comment: no idea about `numweights`, but each of 6 face-squares is made of 4 vertices, and they don't share vertices because the normals are different. Hence, 24 vertices.

Comment: @Jimmy thanks for the confirmation on what I thought. So it's exporting fine, 6 faces *  4 verts = 24 verts. I'd answer the question but it's still on hold.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, it's pretty common for 3D packages to create duplicate vertices when exporting. 3D Studio Max definitely did this the last time I looked at it.

I know this can happen when a vertex has more than one set of texture coordinates, which can happen depending on how you texture mapped the cube. I think you can minimise this depending on how you unwrap for texturing.

Ultimately though, unless your model is extremely complicated and there are a massive number of duplicated vertices, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Actually, there is likely not any unnecessarily duplicated vertices.  Due to having different normals, corners on different sides cannot use the same vertex, irrespective of texture coordinates.  Jimmy mentioned this in his comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

As Bryan mentioned, it's because the cube is stored as 4 distinct quads.  6 faces * 4 verts/quad = 24 verts.

Figuring out where you can save a vertex or two (by re-using vertices and having an index buffer) may not be worth doing for many reasons.

1. Normals are often different
2. Texcoords are almost certainly different
3. Forcing use of index buffers by the rendering engine isn't always a good idea

So, having a policy of *always* replicating vertices here (ie storing separate tris and never using index buffers) appears to be what they have done here.  IB's work great for things like terrain, or environments, but it seems it was decided that they would not be used for MD5 models.  It's just an approach and seems to be what worked for them in this particular file format.